# Empty whoami in subshell

Tags: command-line, ssh, webapps

I have a webapp (nginx, gunicorn, python) that receives git post hooks and triggers a command line tool (ruby, capistrano). Everything is run via a user named `deployer`. The command line tool runs very well and can connect via ssh to remote servers.

When the webapp triggers it, it can't connect via ssh. A password is required. I think I know how to circumvent it (i had a similar problem with cronjobs here: [Server gets killed due to increasing number of ssh-agent processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660857/server-gets-killed-due-to-increasing-number-of-ssh-agent-processes)) but somehow the user is empty in the webabb.

Given this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(whoami)"
```

When I run `deployer@tools:/srv/deployment$ ./test > test.txt` then test.txt contains "deployer" and the file `test.txt` is owned by deployer:deployer.

When I run the very same command from within my webapp then test.txt is empty (only containing a line break) but owned by deployer:www-data (as expected and configured in gunicorn).

How is that even possible and what may I do about that?

Comment: But.. why are you running `echo $(whoami)` instead of just `whoami`? And when you say you ran the very same command from the app, how did you do that?

Comment: `whoami` brings the same result (without the linebreak, just an empty file and i run it with `os.system('cd /srv/deployment && ./test > test.txt')` from within the python app.

Comment: What if you run `os.system('whoami > test.txt')`, or use `id -u` instead of `whoami`, or use `echo $USER`?

Comment: Interestingly `whoami` pure returns 127 instead of 0 as return code.

Comment: What's the `PATH` in your webapp? What if you give full path to `whoami` (`/usr/bin/whoami`, IIRC)?

Comment: Now we are talking. It's the virtualenv of python. Can i have two PATH variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30138/discussion-between-muru-and-shredding).

Answer (score 1):

So the problem turned out to be a different path setting.

Gunicorn was using the python virtualenv as PATH and therefore did not know whoami at all. Pushing in absolute path worked!